# C# - Comparing multiple files with one other file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a method that does the following:

Removes all instances in FileA from FileB by outputting them in FileC

If I wanted to do the same but compare FileA and FileD* against FileB, what would I add?

Code:

```
private static void CompareFiles()
{
    File.WriteAllLines("FileC.txt",
    File.ReadAllLines("FileB.txt").Except(File.ReadAllLines("FileA.txt")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.WriteAllLines("FileC.txt", File.ReadAllLines("FileB.txt").Except(File.ReadAllLines("FileA.txt")).Except(File.ReadAllLines("FileD.txt")));
```

Admittedly, not entirely sure this would work. But take the result from the first Except, and call Except on that again with FileD.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void CompareFiles()
{
    File.WriteAllLines("FileC.txt",
    File.ReadAllLines("FileB.txt").Except(File.ReadAllLines("FileA.txt")
                                        .Union(File.ReadAllLines("FileD.txt"))));
}
```